# Disabling Scroll with System.Console.Write

Tags: vb.net, console

Is it possible to use Console.Write to place a single character at the very bottom right of a typical 80x25 console, without having the console scroll the row up? This is the code that I'm using...

```
Imports System
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth-1, Console.WindowHeight-1)
Console.Write("x")
```

This is not working like I would like it to. Any suggestions or alternatives? I've tested that SetCursorPosition does use a 0,0 coordinate system, already. Using the WindowWidth-1/Height-1 should put me in the lower right corner of the screen... which it does, but then Console.Write is putting the "x" down and continuing on to the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try moving the buffer area. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Top")
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth - 1, Console.WindowHeight - 1)
Console.Write("x")
Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 0, 80, 25, 0, 1)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: For that to work the BufferArea already has to be bigger than the Console Dimensions, which on many consoles results in nasty scrollbars. At that point one might just scroll up via the console-API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whenever you write to the last location in a particular line, the console always moves you to the next line.  The closest thing you can do is write to the second last location:

```
        Console.CursorLeft = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
        Console.Write("X");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a dirty but functional way.

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(79, 24); //last pos
Console.BufferWidth++;
Console.Write("x");
Console.BufferWidth--;
Console.ReadKey();
```

the side of the box does flicker a millisecond, but I don't think anyone will ever notice :)

Comment: I know I would. And I'll bet I'm not alone.